# PF Firewall : Every time I use `pfctl`, I get errors about ALTQ support

Tags: firewall, logs, pfctl

I have a slightly elaborate firewall setup where my server usually has between 400 and 800 ip addresses firewalled. It switches back and forth between two different `pf` tables. Every day it rebuilds the firewall list in the new table and flushes the old one. It does this all via script and it works very well.

But the problem is this `ALTQ` error. Every time you use `pfctl` for anything, the first thing it does is output two error lines:

```
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
```

Problem is my script runs `pfctl` hundreds of times per day. The error log for my script is growing WAY too fast.

Is there any way to suppress these error messages? `pfctl` does have a `-q` flag but that's only for ignoring non-error output. Is there a way I can more fully disable ALTQ in the config file so it won't even try to use it?

Note that I don't know what ALTQ is, but I know I don't need it. My firewall works perfectly aside from the log flood.

Comment: I gotta ask, why are you running pfctl *hundreds of times per day*?

Comment: @Allan I keep my master list of bad hosts in sql. Every day at 3am or so, my server rebuilds that list into a new `pf` table, then empties the old table. This is how old bans expire. Depending on how much bad traffic there's been lately, the number of blocked hosts can be large.

Comment: With `pfctl` you can update only a small part of ruleset using its anchors mechanism

Answer (score 3):

I am probably missing something, because this does not seem to be a complex question. If you what to screen out these 2 error messages, then enter the command given below.

```
pfctl >2 >(grep -v -e "No ALTQ support in kernel" -e "ALTQ related functions disabled" 1>&2)
```

I omitted any parameters that would normally occur between `pfctl` and `>2`. A function could be defined which would simplify the use of this command. One such function implementation is shown below.

```
pfctl() {
    command pfctl "$@" >2 >(grep -v -e "No ALTQ support in kernel" -e "ALTQ related functions disabled" 1>&2)
}
```

Under certain conditions, the above solution could result in the output appearing "*out of order*". This could be corrected by piping the output through the `cat` command. In other words, you could use the command given below.

```
pfctl >2 >(grep -v -e "No ALTQ support in kernel" -e "ALTQ related functions disabled" 1>&2) | cat
```

Also the function could be replaced with the one given below.

```
pfctl() {
    command pfctl "$@" >2 >(grep -v -e "No ALTQ support in kernel" -e "ALTQ related functions disabled" 1>&2) | cat
}
```

**References**
[Bash Redirections Cheat Sheet](https://catonmat.net/ftp/bash-redirections-cheat-sheet.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

This means that the macOS kernel is missing ALTQ support. Basically, ALTQ are optional various queues in the kernel used by pf(4) for better packets queueing. All of them are disabled inside the kernel and there's no option to enable it.

In your case you might just ignore these lines.

In other OS like OpenBSD or FreeBSD, you can compile kernel with ALTQ enabled (it's a compile-time feature)

Comment: I understand all that. But for an optional feature, you'd think there would be a way to mute the constant complaining about it. (without having to grep the output)

Comment: pfctl(8) has no such option. It warns you to not use ALTQ-related functionality in pf.conf(5)

Answer (score 0):

I am just having the same problem as yours in a shell script.
I resolved it by writing the pfctl command this way :

```
sudo pfctl -s info 2> /dev/null
```

This send the error output to trash but keeps the standard output.
I found the answer here : https://www.baeldung.com/linux/silencing-bash-output